# Google Sheets IMPORTRANGE not working dynamically when worksheet is Programmatically updated via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I am using `Python` and `gspread` to upload local .csv data to a google **`SpreadsheetA`**.

I have a separate google **`SpreadsheetB`** that uses `=IMPORTRANGE`  to import the data from `SpreadsheetA` and create a pivot table and corresponding chart (both located on SpreadsheetB).

If I were to manually adjust any data in `SpreadsheetA` (e.g., alter value of any cell, add a value to an empty cell, etc), then the data in `SpreadsheetB`—with its corresponding pivot table and chart—update dynamically with the new data from `SpreadsheetA`.

However, when `SpreadsheetA` is updated with new data programmatically via Python, `IMPORTRANGE` in `SpreadsheetB` does not capture the new data.

Any ideas as to why this happens and how I might be able to fix?

Comment: Please share a link to your sheet B

Comment: @JohnA Here is the link to [SpreadsheetB](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MATRUHTde_U6oG7oDjsCfwI0PBzZHLryl78R5G8VAPI)

Comment: Both sheet A and B show 567 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although probably not the ideal, my solution to this was to use `gspread` to add a new `worksheet` to `spreadsheetA`, which somehow manages to kickstart `importrange()` in `SpreadsheetB`.

I would still love to see a cleaner solution, if anyone knows of one—but this has continued to work since implementing a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

Both Sheet A and B show the same number of rows. I am a bit confused with your IMPORTRANGE() formula though, why the ampersand?

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16DyWC8rsQB1ThpLiQh0p5xH9CYK2cPqbPH547ybw2Fo/edit#gid=1875728384",""&"TestgAPI!A:J")
```

I changed to this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16DyWC8rsQB1ThpLiQh0p5xH9CYK2cPqbPH547ybw2Fo/edit#gid=1875728384","TestgAPI!A:J")
```

Comment: the ampersand was part of a temporary test that I was implementing to try and force an update in SpreadsheetB.  The two spreadsheets currently show the same number of rows because I had manually updated spreadsheetA (causing the reload/update of data on spreadsheetB). If you check again, you will see that spreadsheetA now has 1024rows (after updating via python) but spreadsheetB is still stuck at the previous 568 rows.

Comment: I checked sheet A and B settings, I am not sure if it makes a difference, but they are set for 2 different timezones

Comment: I think I just saw you on spreadsheetA.  Feel free to change one of the values in column D of sheetA, if you would like to see how a manual (human-executed) update to sheetA will result in the update of sheetB.

Comment: I changed spreadhseetA to Eastern time, then updated again via Python.  There are now 1056 rows in sheetA, but it is back on Pacific timezone and sheetB is still stuck at 1024...

Comment: I changed the column name from Counter to Counters and that seemed to force an update

Comment: Yes, I noticed the change in sheetA—as well as the anticipated corresponding update in sheetB.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to update again via Python (in order to create another asymmetry between the sheets).

Comment: FWIW, I also changed the calculation setting for Sheet B and added a timestamp, go ahead and update, give it one minute and let's see what happens

Comment: Updated—sheetB still stuck at 1056

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234080/discussion-between-zwitrader-and-johna).

Comment: Try adding rows to Sheet A again

Comment: did you see that I wrote to you [via chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234080/discussion-between-zwitrader-and-johna)?